# raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but " ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am doing some iterations and incrementing the following variables:

```
a_wins = 0
b_wins = 0
c_loss_due_to_energy = 0
```

I'm just using the usual `a_wins += 1`, `b_wins += 1`, and `c_loss_due_to_energy += 1`.

I'm then trying to plot the results as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(x, a_score, label = 'a wins')
plt.plot(x, b_score, label = 'b wins')
plt.plot(x, c_loss_due_to_energy, label = 'c losses due to energy')

plt.xlabel("Batch Number")
plt.legend()
plt.title('multiple plots')
plt.show()
```

I'm appending the values to the variables as follows:

```
a_score.append(a_wins)
b_score.append(b_wins)
c_loss_due_to_energy_score.append(c_loss_due_to_energy)
x = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    x.append(i)
```

Their final values are printed as follows:

```
print(x)
print(a_score)
print(b_score)
print(c_loss_due_to_energy_score)

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[7, 8, 7, 9, 5, 6, 7, 9, 9, 6]
[3, 2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4]
[5, 6, 5, 5, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, 3]
```

So, as you can see, this all looks consistent. But, for some reason, I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/project/testing.py", line 115, in <module>
    plt.plot(x, blue_loss_due_to_energy, label = 'b losses due to energy')
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2730, in plot
    return gca().plot(
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 1662, in plot
    lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 311, in __call__
    yield from self._plot_args(
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 504, in _plot_args
    raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10,) and (1,)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[7, 8, 7, 9, 5, 6, 7, 9, 9, 6]
[3, 2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4]
[5, 6, 5, 5, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, 3]
```

This seems to be a relatively common error, but I can't seem to find a way to fix it. After all, given the print output, there doesn't even seem to be a problem here ...

Comment: Show the FULL error message!  Asking for that, or the traceback, is even more common than this error.

Comment: Have you done any of your own debugging?  Or did you just do a general (or SO) web search, without trying to understand the error or its cause?  Does a shape of (1,) make sense for the 2nd variable?

Comment: I agree with hpaulj, but it seems you plot `c_loss_due_to_energy` instead of `..._score` or something similar.

Comment: @hpaulj What do you mean? Does the print not show that they have the same structure?

Comment: @hpaulj Would you please elaborate on the issue?

Comment: Note that, in order to write a good question, you need a fully reproducible test example, together with the full error trace (in your current post, you don't show which line exactly gives the error).

Comment: @JohanC In my program, the print statements come before the plotting statements. I will edit the post with the full trace now.

Comment: It seems `blue_loss_due_to_energy` has length 1 when you are plotting it.  Could you create a fully independent, reproducible example?  Your question isn't answerable with the information provided.

Comment: Right, the only array you didn't show us is the one causing the error...

Comment: @JohanC Yes, you were correct, it works now!!! Thanks so much everyone. Sorry if this was annoying at all; I really appreciate you taking the time to help me.